# Add class to an element if its content equals specified value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I'm trying to have a class added if an element is blank or has a value of zero.

The HTML is generated by the platform I'm using and cannot be adjusted without using scripts, so I'm restricted to JavaScript / jQuery and CSS to make the adjustments.

Here's what I have and I just can't quite get it.

#### HTML

```
<div class="Widget1001783 WidgetType23 microCart" id="w1001783_pnlDefaultBody">
    <table width="100%">
        <tbody>
            <tr id="w1001783_trHeader">
                <th colspan="2"> <span class="FormLabel" id="w1001783_lblCart">shopping cart</span> </th>
            </tr>
            <tr id="w1001783_trItems">
                <td><span class="FormLabel" id="w1001783_lblItems">items:</span></td>
                <td align="right"><span class="FormLabel" id="w1001783_lbdItems">0</span></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

#### CSS

```
.microCart tr:nth-of-type(2) td:last-child::after {
   content: "♣";
}

.microCart.emptyCart tr:nth-of-type(2) td:last-child,
.emptyCart *::after {
    content:"";
    display:none;
}
```

#### jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
      if ($(".microCart tr:nth-of-type(2) td:last-child span").html("0"))
           $(".microCart").addClass("emptyCart");
      else ($(".microCart").removeClass("emptyCart"));
});
```

Comment: Why do we see this type of confusion so frequently? There's nothing in any jQuery documentation or tutorial that suggests that calling functions with an argument performs a comparison.

Comment: Where did you get the impression that `.html("0")` is the way to test if the HTML is `0`?

Comment: @Barmar Unfortunately people tend to try some random things, and if it's not working, they prefer to bother people on Stack Overflow instead of reading the docs.

Comment: @Gothdo I understand that, but the newbies all seem to hit on this same random thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you pass anything to `html()` function - then it sets that to the inner html of the element - [see documentation](http://api.jquery.com/html/#html2). So in your example you're not comparing the html of the element to 0, rather you set the html value of the node to it. Which is why it doesn't work as you expected.

Mostly that's all what needs to be fixed.

The other thing is that usage of `text()` is better, as you're not interested in all the possible tags inside the element. The example is below.

```js
function updateClass() {
  var $cart = $(".microCart");
  var text = $cart.find("tr:nth-of-type(2) td:last-child span").text().trim();
  if ((text == "0") || !text.length)
      $cart.addClass("emptyCart");
  else 
      $cart.removeClass("emptyCart");
}
```

```css
.microCart tr:nth-of-type(2) td:last-child::after {
   content: "♣";
}

.microCart.emptyCart tr:nth-of-type(2) td:last-child,
.emptyCart *::after {
    content:"";
    display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="Widget1001783 WidgetType23 microCart" id="w1001783_pnlDefaultBody">
    <table width="100%">
        <tbody>
            <tr id="w1001783_trHeader">
                <th colspan="2"> <span class="FormLabel" id="w1001783_lblCart">shopping cart</span> </th>
            </tr>
            <tr id="w1001783_trItems">
                <td><span class="FormLabel" id="w1001783_lblItems">items:</span></td>
                <td align="right"><span class="FormLabel" id="w1001783_lbdItems">0</span></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>

<input type="button" value="Set class" onclick="updateClass()"/>
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to call the `html()` method with no arguments, and then compare the result to `"0"`. And in fact, if you want to get the text content of an element, you should use the `text()` method. You should also `trim()` the result, in case there are some spaces inside this element.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  const value = $(".microCart tr:nth-of-type(2) td:last-child span").text().trim()
  if (value === "0" || value === "") {
    $(".microCart").addClass("emptyCart");
  } else {
    $(".microCart").removeClass("emptyCart");
  }
});
```

See [jQuery docs on `text()` method](http://api.jquery.com/text/).

Comment: @AndreyTserkus I added a check for blank text. And it's considered a good coding practice to always use strict comparison operators.

Answer (score 1):

Change the if condition to:

```
if ($(".microCart tr:nth-of-type(2) td:last-child span").html().localeCompare("")==0 || 
$(".microCart tr:nth-of-type(2) td:last-child span").html().localeCompare("0")==0)
```

`$("selector").html("string")` sets the `innerHTML` property to `"string"`.